# How can I get the exact dimensions of an SVG tspan element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to retrieve the exact dimensions of an SVG tspan element.

Please check with the screenshot[image]

For example, take this input:

```html
<text 
    fill="#000000" 
    stroke="none" 
    stroke-width="0" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
    stroke-linejoin="round" 
    x="32"
    y="25.84627776450299" 
    text-anchor="middle" 
    font-size="27px" 
    font-family="Old English" 
    data-textcurve="0" 
    data-itemzoom="1 1"  
    itemzoom="0.1927710843373494 0.2872340425531915">
    <tspan dy="0" x="50%">Hello</tspan>
    <tspan dy="27" x="50%">Hello</tspan>
</text>
```

I tried the following code, but it does not return the exact width and height of the text.

```js
var size1 = txt[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var w = parseInt(size1.width);          
var size2 = e[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: It should get the exact height of the text--the extra pixels you are seeing is due to the difference between the height of individual glyphs vs line-height

Comment: @Terry could you help me out how to get the widht and height

Comment: You're rounding the width to an int, what else is wrong with the width/height?

Comment: @RobertLongson I need the actual width and height of text. I tried different function to get it using getboudingclientreact not getting exact width and height

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is wrong with the width and height? Height too big, width too small, completely wrong, something else?

Comment: @RobertLongson Please check with the screenshot. the box dimension should touch the font.

Comment: That's not possible, there is no API that will get you that information.